# Running dash from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run dash through jupyter notebook but the app is not launching. I get SystemExit: 1 error. Kindly help. I am not asking to run within notebook but just to launch the web app. if I use a app.py file, it runs but why I can not run through jupyter notebook?

```
'''
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='cytoscape',
        elements=[
            {'data': {'id': 'one', 'label': 'Node 1'}, 'position': {'x': 50, 'y': 50}},
            {'data': {'id': 'two', 'label': 'Node 2'}, 'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 200}},
            {'data': {'source': 'one', 'target': 'two','label': 'Node 1 to 2'}}
        ],
        layout={'name': 'preset'}
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True,port=5001)
```

I get this error:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/
Debugger PIN: 699-998-824
Debugger PIN: 699-998-824
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1


/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3275: UserWarning:

To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
```

%tb for this flask issue:

[Flask issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf37a.png)

Comment: "use %tb to see the full traceback" did you try that?

Comment: Yes some flask error. I updated with screenshot link.

Answer (score 1):

@idontcare You have to change few lines to run this code in jupyter notebook. first install jupyter plotly dash with

[pip install jupyter-plotly-dash] 
The Django in this installation needs to be set by installing 
[pip install -U django-plotly-dash==0.9.8].

Then the dash that comes with jupyter-plotly-dash installation have a bug and needs to be downgraded to 0.38.0. you can install this with 
[pip install dash==0.38.0]

see updated code:

'''

```
from jupyter_plotly_dash import JupyterDash
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html

app = JupyterDash('YourAppExample')

app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='cytoscape',
        elements=[
            {'data': {'id': 'one', 'label': 'Node 1'}, 'position': {'x': 50, 'y': 50}},
            {'data': {'id': 'two', 'label': 'Node 2'}, 'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 200}},
            {'data': {'source': 'one', 'target': 'two','label': 'Node 1 to 2'}}
        ],
        layout={'name': 'preset'}
    )
])

app
```